# How do I create a soap client programmatically with a WSSE security header using a certificate

Tags: c#, soap

I need to consume a soap service but have no experience in soap/WCF etc.  I have the following extract that is the XML created (some sections removed for security) and need to create the soap client programmatically in c# that generates this.

Really hoping there is a soap guru out there who can help.

Thanks in advance

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" wsu:Id="X509-1C5E89F97CB6F0E5FF169659964870427">Removed for security</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        <ds:Signature Id="SIG-1C5E89F97CB6F0E5FF169659964870930" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                    <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsa soapenv urn" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#TS-1C5E89F97CB6F0E5FF169659964870326">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse wsa soapenv urn" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </ds:Transform>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>Removed for security</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>Removed for security</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-1C5E89F97CB6F0E5FF169659964870428">
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" wsu:Id="STR-1C5E89F97CB6F0E5FF169659964870429" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
                    <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-1C5E89F97CB6F0E5FF169659964870427" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1"/>
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-1C5E89F97CB6F0E5FF169659964870326">
            <wsu:Created>2023-10-06T13:40:48.703Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2023-10-06T13:42:18.703Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1C5E89F97CB6F0E5FF169659964870325">
            <wsse:Username>Removed for security</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Removed for security</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">Removed for security</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2023-10-06T13:40:48.703Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
    <wsa:Action>Removed for security</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>uuid:eed66883-af90-4141-9185-f66a4fe7e039</wsa:MessageID>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    
</soapenv:Body>
```

</soapenv:Envelope>